# Code compiles on Windows and Linux but not Mac

Tags: macos, qt, gnu-make

I am compiling a project on multiple platforms with the c++0x flag. The only platform I am having trouble on is Mac. It seems to get upset over things that other compilers let slide. I am using Mac 10.8, Qt 5.3.2 with the following version of clang.

```
clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

This is the error it is generating.

```
In file included from src/qt/bitcoin.cpp:5:
In file included from ../../Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/QApplication:1:
In file included from ../../Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qapplication.h:45:
In file included from /Users/user/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qcoreapplication.h:45:
In file included from /Users/user/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:78:
In file included from /Users/user/Qt5.3.2/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qcompilerdetection.h:846:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/utility:254:9: error: field has incomplete type 'CScript'
_T2 second;
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:1994:27: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::pair<const CScriptID, CScript>'
  requested here
             decltype(__is_constructible_test(declval<_Tp>(), declval<_Args>()...))
                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2043:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__is_constructible<false,
  std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const CScriptID, CScript> >>' requested here
: public __is_constructible<is_scalar<_Tp>::value || is_reference<_Tp>::value,
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2069:14: note: in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::__is_constructible_void_check<false, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const CScriptID, CScript> >>' requested here
: public __is_constructible_void_check<__contains_void<_Tp, _Args...>::value
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2549:34: note: in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::is_constructible<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const CScriptID, CScript> >>' requested here
: __is_nothrow_constructible<is_constructible<_Tp, _Args...>::value, _Tp, _Args...>
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:2671:14: note: in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::is_nothrow_constructible<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const CScriptID, CScript> >>' requested here
: public is_nothrow_constructible<_Tp>
         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:840:13: note: in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::is_nothrow_default_constructible<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const CScriptID, CScript> > >' requested here
        is_nothrow_default_constructible<allocator_type>::value &&
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:332:34: note: expanded from macro '_NOEXCEPT_'
#  define _NOEXCEPT_(x) noexcept(x)
                             ^
src/keystore.h:43:7: note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'map' requested here
class CBasicKeyStore : public CKeyStore
  ^
src/serialize.h:28:7: note: forward declaration of 'CScript'
class CScript;
  ^
src/keystore.h:116:5: note: implicit default constructor for 'CBasicKeyStore' first required here
CCryptoKeyStore() : fUseCrypto(false)
^
```

Comment: Show us the code generating the error (with enough context). Also: try updating your toolchain (Clang and libc++), might be a bug that has already been fixed in either.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, it seems to be related with clang and c++11.

My scenario:
 - Mac osx 10.10.1 yosemite
 - Xcode 6.1 with Command Line tools 6.1
 - Gnu make 3.81
 - gcc -v:
     Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
     Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
     Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
     Thread model: posix
No homebrew, no macports, just some dependencies compiled by hand.

I am trying to compile for x86_64.

Any clue?

My idea could be recompile every dependency with gcc instead of clang, but I still had not time to test it, maybe it works for you ;)